# Redirect URL within Apache VirtualHost?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect, virtualhost

I have a dedicated server with Apache, on which I've set up some VirtualHosts. I've set up one to handle the www domain as well as the non-www domain.

My VH .conf file for the www:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/site
  ServerName www.example.com
  <Directory "/var/www/site">
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

With this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Is there a simple way to redirect the www to the non-www version? Currently I'm sending both versions to the same `DocumentRoot` and using `.htaccess` but I'm sure I must be able to do it in the VirtualHost file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42500012/apache-rewritecond-not-working-if-then/42512986#42512986

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Turns out `mod_rewrite` rules are fine in the VirtualHosts file, apart from the `RewriteBase` rule. I ended up with this:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName www.example.com
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT: on the advice of joschi in the comments, I'm now using this simplified version using the [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive from `mod_alias`:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName www.example.com
  Redirect 301 / http://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You do not need mod_rewrite for this. Use mod_alias and its RedirectPermanent directive instead.

Comment: @joschi: What would be the advantage of that? Is it faster?

Comment: You don't need the full-blown rewrite engine with all its checks and possibilities to just redirect the client. It would be (marginally) faster since mod_alias is not near as complex as mod_rewrite and you'd only need one directive (RedirectPermanent) instead of two with mod_rewrite. And last but not least IMHO it's easier to understand what happens in the configuration when someone looks at it the first time.

Comment: For some strange reason Redirect 301 .. did not work for us. We had to use the RewriteRule option.

Comment: NOTE: Using PHP 5.3.0 on WAMPSERVER 2.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, not including `:80` after `VirtualHost *` causes *everything* to return "Forbidden"!

Comment: works fine (the second one) but it doesn't change url. still shows www in the url ?

Comment: It is safer to omit the '301' unless you **really** want a **permanent** redirect. The default is 302 Found, which would work better for a lot of people. See http://jacquesmattheij.com/301-redirects-a-dangerous-one-way-street

Comment: I attempted to use the Redirect solution to force an HTTPS connection when the user tries to connect with HTTP.  However the HTTP connection still generated the default 400 error, and an HTTPS connection failed with the browser error "too many redirects."

Answer (score 5):

Be very careful with 301 redirects because, by default, a browser that receives the 301 redirect will store it permanently - meaning you will give up control what that browser will see when it tries to access the domain `www.example.com`.

See for example this discussion http://getluky.net/2010/12/14/301-redirects-cannot-be-undon/

So either make sure it does not get cached, or use mod_proxy (I recommend the mod_proxy).

If you are fine with letting the user see the URL change on the browser address bar, use mod_rewrite:

```
<VirtualHost *>
 ServerName www.example.com
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
 RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,E=nocache:1]
## Set the response header if the "nocache" environment variable is set
## in the RewriteRule above.
 Header always set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" env=nocache
## Set Expires too ...
 Header always set Expires "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" env=nocache
</VirtualHost>
```

If you want the "redirect" to be invisible to the user, use mod_proxy:

```
<VirtualHost *>
 ServerName www.example.com
 ProxyRequests Off
 <Proxy *>
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from 203.0.113.67
 </Proxy>
 ProxyPass / http://example.com/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

It should be noted that mod_proxy, when badly configured, can harm your network.

Comment: The point of a 301 is that it's a *permanent* redirect; if you want a non-permanent redirect, you should use 302 or 307 instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `ServerAlias example.com` to the `VirtualHost` but the performance will differ from a redirect.

**Edit**

Since you want to redirect and you don't need advanced functionality, it seems like using `Redirect` should suffice for you.  You would put the `Redirect` under a VirtualHost directive.

A client side solution would be to use a `meta refresh` tag.

- [mod_alias documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)
- [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)

Comment: Can you explain a bit further? How would I redirect `www.example.com` to `example.com` using this method?

Comment: In your primary vhost, you have entries for both `ServerName` and `ServerAlias`.  One has example.com and the other www.example.com.

Then, both dns entries will access the documents specified in the same vhost.

Comment: I want to do a *redirect* though, not just an alias.

Comment: Then joshchi's recommendation may be a good approach for you.  Seems like hairs are being split at this point.

Answer (score 1):

well, you could create one virtual host for the SERVERNAME www.example.com and have it redirect to another virtual host with the servername example.com