# Apache .htaccess 301 permanent redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, 301-redirect

How can I make it so that whenever a page on `mydomain.com` is accessed without `www` to go to `www.mydomain.com`, please?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this answers your question: http://serverfault.com/questions/120488/redirect-url-within-apache-virtualhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# redirect for http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]

# redirect for https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]
```

`R=301` will redirect with https status 301
`L` will make last rule
`NE` is for no escaping query string
`QSA` will append your existing query parameters

`$1` is your REQUEST_URI

Comment: Your `^(.*)$` will capture the leading slash; you don't want to add a second in the location that you're redirecting to.

Comment: I don't need the FollowSymLinks do I?

Comment: It's not 100% good yet. :) If I enter: mydomain.com/folder/ it will go to www.mydomain.com instead of www.mydomain.com/folder/.

Comment: Also, I would like it to keep `https` if that's how it came.

Comment: @Francisc: Please see my edited answer, that takes care of http and https both.