# How to redirect from /page to /cms/page and hide "cms“ in the URL?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I installed cms at Linux server 10.0.0.1/cms/. I want to redirect every visit to 10.0.0.1/pages to 10.0.0.1/cms/pages, while hide "cms" in the URLs.

Several attempts have been tried but failed.

1> edit /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html" -->   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/cms"
```

This only works for index page. Hyperlinks in the index "10.0.0.1/cms/pages" will become unavailable in this case, as /cms/pages no longer exist in the DocumentRoot directory "/var/www/html/cms".

2> edit /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
Redirect / /cms/
```

This will cause infinite loop 10.0.0.1/cms/cms/cms/...

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cms/$1 [L]
```

You can place this in your `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` inside the vhost you defined (if you have one) or in your `<Directory>` otherwise.

This will redirect all requests made to /cms/something to /something while still still fetching it from /cms/something.

Comment: Could you please provide more details? I edited httpd.conf to AllowOverride All, and then created a .htaccess file under /var/www/html, containing your scripts. It doesn't work so far.

Comment: It still doesn't work, even I place this in both <Directory /> and <Directory /var/www/html> :(

Comment: Take a look here: http://serverfault.com/questions/120488/redirect-url-within-apache-virtualhost

Comment: This method should work, although my final solution is just `mv * ../`, and modify some other config files.