# Redirect from within vhost for multiple sites

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, redirect, virtualhost

Note: My question is similar to [one here](https://serverfault.com/questions/120488/redirect-url-within-apache-virtualhost/120507#120507?newreg=809c8c00027c46b989d1d26e764ea8c1) but I'm trying to achieve something slightly different.

A. I would like to create two `vhosts` on a `ec2` instance that has a elastic ip attached.

B. Each of these two `vhost` definitions redirect a domain to different url on a different site.

i.e

> www.site01.com should redirect fully to http://www.socialsite.com/profile01
>
> www.site02.com should redirect to a category page on a ecommerce site http://www.sellitall.com/cat/0285

C. These are full redirects i.e query strings should be discarded and irrespective of the URL/URI user should be redirected to the given page.

Here is what I tried and unfortunately, only first redirect works and both `site01` and `site02.com` are now redirected to `http://www.socialsite.com/profile01`. Further, query strings are messing up the redirects resulting in page not found errors.

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.140:*>
    ServerName www.site01.com
    Redirect 301 / http://www.socialsite.com/profile01
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.0.0.140:*>
    ServerName www.site02.com
    Redirect 301 / http://www.sellitall.com/cat/0285
</VirtualHost>
```

Output of `httpd -S`:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
10.0.0.140:*           www.site01.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:451)
10.0.0.140:*           www.site02.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:441)
```

Comment: Show the output of `httpd -S`

Comment: @lain updated the post with output of `httpd -S`

Comment: Maybe try ReWrite rules - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118511/htaccess-301-redirect-remove-query-string-qsa

Comment: just add document root (with any existing folder like /var/www/) in both

Comment: Looks like `RewriteRule` is the way to go.