# Apache redirect www and non-www with subdomain to non-www https

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect

I would like to redirect www and non-www with a subdomain to non-www HTTPS.

I think this should clarify.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/www/eshop"
    ServerName shop.example.com
    ServerAlias www.shop.example.com
    
    # shop.example.com should redirect to https://shop.example.com
    # www.shop.example.com should redirect to https://shop.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/www/eshop"
    ServerName shop.example.com
    ServerAlias www.shop.example.com

    # I would like to redirect www and non-www to https://shop.example.com
    
    # https://shop.example.com should redirect to https://shop.example.com
    # https://www.shop.example.com should redirect to https://shop.example.com

    <Directory "C:/www/eshop">
        # some code will go here
    </Directory>
    
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect URL within Apache VirtualHost?](https://serverfault.com/questions/120488/redirect-url-within-apache-virtualhost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)  directive for [simple redirects](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName shop.example.com
    ServerAlias www.shop.example.com
    Redirect "/" "https://shop.example.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.shop.example.com
    Redirect "/" "https://shop.example.com/"
    # ... Maybe some SSL configuration is needed here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/www/eshop"
    ServerName shop.example.com
    # ... Maybe some SSL configuration is needed here

    <Directory "C:/www/eshop">
        # some code will go here
    </Directory>
    
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80> Redirect for shop.example.com works fine, but www.shop.example.com does not work. I get 'This site can’t be reached' message.

Comment: That is probably unrelated to your web server configuration and most likely caused elsewhere. (for example you such an error when the DNS record for  www.shop.example.com does not exist.)

Comment: @HBrujin you were right, there was a problem with DNS